# VS Code how to disable pydocstyle linting in testing files?

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code, lint

I'm currently working on a python project and decided to install pydocstyle to improve my documentation habits. However I don't want pydocstyle to lint my testing files and was wondering how I could create a pattern in settings.json to achieve that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, your test files are prefixed by `test_`, you can add the following code in Settings.json:

```
"python.linting.ignorePatterns": [
    "test_*.py",
]
```

Then your test files are excluded from linting:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Wouldn't that stop pylint from running on the test files too?

Comment: @creamycow. The setting works for all linters, so it will also stop pylint from running the test files.

Comment: I'm still trying to use pydocstyle and flake8 in my testing files.
I tried doing something like 
"python.linting.pydocstyle" : false, [
"test_*.py
],
but that didn't work

Comment: To reproduce your question as soon as possible i also use pydocstyle in my project. The setting i post can be applied to all linters. also from the [pydocstyle usage](https://www.pydocstyle.org/en/2.1.1/usage.html#cli-usage), default is `--match='(?!test_).*\.py'` which matches files that don't start with `test_` but end with `.py`, but when i test on my machine, it didn't work, so i post `"python.linting.ignorePatterns": [
    "test_*.py",
]` cause it can solve your question too.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found solution (but don't ask me why it works though :)

```json
"python.linting.pydocstyleArgs": ["--match=^((?!test).)*$"],
```